# How to search with multiple parameters using paging and sorting repository?

Tags: java, jquery, spring-data-jpa

I am using paging and sorting repository for jquery datatable in my spring project. I tried searching with three parameters as of now like

```
@Query(value = "Select p from ProfileBaseInfo p where p.fullName = :fullName or p.firstName = :firstName or p.lastName = :lastName") 
Page<ProfileBaseInfo> search(@Param("fullName") String fullName,@Param("firstName") String firstName,@Param("lastName") String lastName,Pageable pageable);
```

Now i need to search 5 more parameters additionally with different combinations(i.e. and/or).  I have generated a `dynamic query` based on the parameters searched. (i.e)If a parameter is present, I will join the table and insert the `where` condition. How do I bring the dynamically generated query inside of `@Query` or should I handle this in a different way? Now i what i want is I have to build a criteria like `"SELECT * FROM profile where name=? and fullName=? and title=? and city=? and state=? and country=?" in ***@Query***` Annotation.

I would like to know if there is another way to do because the number of columns in a table can be high.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a Spring bean with implementation of your search method ([Spring Data](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour)). 
@Autowire some bean to talk with DB (EntityManager or similar) and write down whatever query you need.

I'd recommend you to use some kind of wrapper object for all your parameters, like

```
class Parameters {
    String firstName,
    String fullName;
    ...
    Object paramN;

    <<getters-setters ?>>
}
```

and to use CriteriaQuery to construct query according to parameters, like

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ProfileBaseInfo> cq = cb.createQuery(ProfileBaseInfo.class);
Root<ProfileBaseInfo> from = cq.from(ProfileBaseInfo.class);
...
List<Predicate> predicates = Lists.newArrayList();
...
if (param.getFullName() != null) {
     predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(ProfileBaseInfo_.fullName)), param.getFullName().toLowerCase() + "%"))
}
...
cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
```

So you can expand parameters list accroding to needs and there is no need to work with strings.